# Not able to load image in html via jsp:include

Tags: html, jsp

I have 1 JSP page and 1 HTML page. I am including that HTML page in JSP dynamically like below.

```
<jsp:include page="<%=htmlPageURL%>" flush="true" />
```

The `htmpPageUrl` value is `/temp/1232334333.html`

In 1232334333.html, I have an image tag:

```
<img width=135 height=48
src="1232334333_files/image003.jpg"> </img>
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
MyWebApp/temp/1232334333.html
MyWebApp/temp/1232334333_files/image003.jpg
```

The problem is when I include the HTML page in JSP, it displays all the text fine, but could not load the image.

My understanding:

As I include HTML in JSP, all image paths should be relative to my JSP and not my HTML. But I really can't change HTML source. Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: `src="/temp/1232334333_files/image003.jpg"`.

Comment: I can't change the source of html page due to some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<base>` tag does the trick for me.

```
e.g. <base href="http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/temp"></base>
```

Answer (score 0):

img tag is in correct.

```
Wrong:    <img width=135 height=48 src="1232334333_files/image003.jpg" </img>
```

Correct

```
     <img width=135 height=48 src="1232334333_files/image003.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, i just gave example in my origional question. image tag is corrected in question. The problem is not with image tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to your `.html` page to modify the source, then you can try to modify it using jQuery in your `.jsp` file. If you know the position of the `<src />` tag (i supposed it's in the first position after the page is included), when you can do as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img:first").attr("src","/temp/1232334333_files/image003.jpg");
    var src = $("img:first").attr("src");
    alert(src);
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- The following image is inserted after the <jsp:include /> function is processed -->
<img width=135 height=48 src="1232334333_files/image003.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

The alert function will display `/temp/1232334333_files/image003.jpg`.
I'm not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.